# Check validation if other field has value as well as check field has specific value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I am doing a project in Laravel and adding some validation rule on my form. Here, I have situation where I a field "A" is required if field "B" has specific value. And after field "A" is required then I want to validate value of field "A".

I am trying to do achieve the same using "required_if" validation rule as given below:

```
['years' => 'required_if:duration_type,0,gt:0'];
```

Here I want to check if duration type is 0 then my "years" field must be required and value just greater than 0.

Can someone please guide me on how can I achieve the same?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: put the condition for it in second one which you want to validate when required

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `DataAwareRule` Rule as laravel's doc explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects).

I wrote a sample rule for you that implemented this interface, and retrieves for example `b` parameter and assigns it to `b` property of rule object, then you can use it in `passes()` method.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\DataAwareRule;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ARule implements Rule, DataAwareRule
{
    protected $b;

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if ($this->b == 'specific_value') {
            
            if ($value == 'valid_value') {
                return true;
            }
            
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }

    public function setData($data)
    {
        $this->b = data_get($data, 'b');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have livewire component need to validate a condition like this.

https://ibb.co/Sd8PQBx

1. Less than Max Mark
2. Not less than 0
3. A for absent need to validate the conditions if any one condition is true need to accept.

Comment: Hi @VPR. It's a good idea to post your question along with your attempts so far. That way everyone can see your problem and help you.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

`[years => exclude_unless:duration_type,0,required,gt:0];`

Comment: user18079544, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is,

```
['years' => 'exclude_unless:duration_type,==,0|required|numeric|gt:0'];
```

`exclude_unless` will exclude the rule unless duration_type is 0. When duration_type is 0, years will be `required`. And `gt` rule should work properly here when it is `numeric`.